# Is there a way to draw Strings in libgdx without BitmapFonts?

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I want to draw Strings in my Libgdx game but i cant use BitMap Fonts because the scale of my game is to smal to use them.

Comment: Can you use FreeTypeFont?

Comment: I'm not shure if i can use freeType. My game is very zoomed in because i use box2d. I would need a size of the bitMap below 1. if i draw something its just looks like that. https://puu.sh/DwaH5/879964c34d.png My viewport is just 12,8 pixel wight and 7.2 pixel height,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you mean the scale of your viewport is too small to show fonts correctly. There are two solutions. The first is better for legibility while the second is quick and dirty.

One is to use a second viewport for the UI that has an appropriate scale for text. You would first call `gameViewport.apply()`, draw the game, and end the batch. Then use `uiViewport.apply()` and then draw the UI. The downside with this method would be if you want to draw text that aligns with moving objects in the game, you would have to use the two viewports to convert coordinates. Otherwise, this is the ideal method to get a crisp looking UI. Ideally you would use a ScreenViewport and select a font size at runtime based on the screen dimensions, either by shipping your game with multiple versions of the font at different scales, or by using FreeTypeFontGenerator.

The second method is to scale down all your text. First call `bitmapFont.setUseIntegerPositions(false)` do it won't round off positions to integers. Then call `bitmapFont.setScale()` with however much you want to shrink it to fit in your game viewport.

Comment: Realy nice idea i wouldn't came up with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gdx-freetype project:

https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300

and it uses TrueType fonts as source to generate bitmap font on the fly.

Not sure how stable this is - didn't use it.